# BeanAlreadyExistsException - Oracle WebLogic

Tags: java, oracle, servlets, weblogic

I deployed an app on my web server and now I am trying to deply another one on the web server and I am getting a BeanAlreadyExistsException. I thought it might be due to the fact that I have two beans with the same name in the two different projects. So I removed the first project from the server - however that didn't work - I still ended up getting this exception when deploying the second app.

Here is the stack trace:

```
####<Jun 29, 2012 11:35:47 AM EDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <GAATLITISDAU88W> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1340984147265> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application 'jwds0002.ear'.> 
####<Jun 29, 2012 11:35:47 AM EDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <GAATLITISDAU88W> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1340984147265> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: Unmarshaller failed
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeploymentFactory.findOrCreateComponentMBeans(EarDeploymentFactory.java:193)
    at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.findOrCreateComponentMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:48)
    at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.createComponentMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:110)
    at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.initializeMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:76)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.MBeanConverter.createApplicationMBean(MBeanConverter.java:89)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.MBeanConverter.createApplicationForAppDeployment(MBeanConverter.java:67)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.MBeanConverter.setupNew81MBean(MBeanConverter.java:315)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.compatibilityProcessor(ActivateOperation.java:81)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.setupPrepare(AbstractOperation.java:295)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:97)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused By: weblogic.descriptor.BeanAlreadyExistsException: Bean already exists: "weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.wl.ApplicationParamBeanImpl@b68b07b2(/ApplicationParams[webapp.encoding.default])"
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.ReferenceManager.registerBean(ReferenceManager.java:231)
    at weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.wl.WeblogicApplicationBeanImpl.setApplicationParams(WeblogicApplicationBeanImpl.java:564)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:48)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.RuntimeBindingType$BeanRuntimeProperty.setValue(RuntimeBindingType.java:539)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.AttributeRuntimeBindingType$QNameRuntimeProperty.fillCollection(AttributeRuntimeBindingType.java:381)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.MultiIntermediary.getFinalValue(MultiIntermediary.java:52)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.AttributeRuntimeBindingType.getFinalObjectFromIntermediary(AttributeRuntimeBindingType.java:140)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.unmarshalBindingType(UnmarshalResult.java:200)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshalResult.unmarshalDocument(UnmarshalResult.java:169)
    at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:65)
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(MarshallerFactory.java:150)
    at weblogic.descriptor.BasicDescriptorManager.createDescriptor(BasicDescriptorManager.java:323)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.getDescriptorBeanFromReader(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:788)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.createDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:409)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBeanWithoutPlan(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:759)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:768)
    at weblogic.application.ApplicationDescriptor.getWeblogicApplicationDescriptor(ApplicationDescriptor.java:324)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeploymentFactory.findOrCreateComponentMBeans(EarDeploymentFactory.java:181)
    at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.findOrCreateComponentMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:48)
    at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.createComponentMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:110)
    at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.initializeMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:76)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.MBeanConverter.createApplicationMBean(MBeanConverter.java:89)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.MBeanConverter.createApplicationForAppDeployment(MBeanConverter.java:67)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.MBeanConverter.setupNew81MBean(MBeanConverter.java:315)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.compatibilityProcessor(ActivateOperation.java:81)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.setupPrepare(AbstractOperation.java:295)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:97)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
```

> 

Here is the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>jwds0002</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>PubAlertAccessor</display-name>
    <servlet-name>PubAlertAccessor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myPackage.PubAlertAccessor</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PubAlertAccessor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/PubAlertAccessor</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.myPackage.Configurator</listener-class>
  </listener>      
</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you paste your weblogic-application.xml This error is usually indicative of duplication of certain elements. In this case <application-param> element with value - webapp.encoding.default

Comment: My experience: that message comes from Spring IOC which is used by weblogic: that means "Beans" are not your (Enterprise) Java Beans so there cannot be any collision at that level. The error refers instead to container resources (or references to them) like datasource, jms or javamail session or the application itaself

Comment: It's like Andrea says. These sounds like your descriptors are trying to create a resource object that already exists...

Answer (score 0):

You may try getting rid of "**app-deployment**" section from the /base_domain/config/config.xml, which contains the ear/war
**

**

Comment: Please don't post answers like this because this is a comment. If you keep doing this you will be rendered unable to ask questions in SO due to the down votes you going to receive. So please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering), I'm trying to help not being rood.

Comment: It's a comment which you should put under comments under the main question. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) to understand how to answer correctly.

Comment: there's a saying never do the things for free, telling people how to comment and where to is what you're getting paid for, then keeping doing it man cz you're still not at its best.

Answer (score 0):

Open youu   **weblogic.xml**  file  .And see the  **library-ref**  tags . Most probably there is a duplication reference to the  *webapp.encoding.default*  ( this is library that mentioned in your log )

Answer (score -1):

simply remove multiple library reference from weblogic-application.xml file .

adf.oracle.domain

Comment: Can you explain a little bit further?

Answer (score -2):

1. `cd $DOMAIN_HOME`
2. `cd config/jdbc`
3. Delete to xml file of config
4. Restart server